# UPS for Pi 3B and hdd

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, alternative-power, ups

I'm quite new to the Pi world, but I need a UPS unit to power both a Raspberry Pi 3B and a 2.5'' hard disk used by the Pi.
I thought a power bank could be the right choice for me, but I cannot find a good one with 2 usb port with *pass-through* feature.
If it would be the case, would it be a good idea to have a power bank on charge 24/7? How much impact would it have on the power costs?
Of course I'm also open to something different from a power bank as UPS.

Comment: It would be as bad as a phone on 24/7. So if it has a good circuit, I do not think you will break the powerbank. But you need a PB with pass through, I am not sure if they do that by default.